# how to connect HAL using dbus

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, microphone, dbus

I'm using python and dbus. What i really need is a way to get the input from my microphone into my python program and then play it back from the program. I googled a lot and it seems pyaudio might do the trick but pyaudio does not work with my ubuntu 10.04.

The next option i saw was telepathy. But i don't need something that big, either. Seeing how telepathy works over dbus, i fugured this might be the way to go.

Unfortunately i'm unable to connect to the Harware Abstraction LAyer ans use it to get the input from my microphone. Is there any way to do this, or should i seek elsewhere?

Comment: @user409345, most people would take the opportunity of a larger text entry control to actually _elaborate and expand_ on their title, rather than just repeating it. Otherwise you'll get some wag answering and/or commenting with "how to connect HAL using dbus" like this:

Comment: how to connect HAL using dbus

Comment: See how annoying that was? If the author wasn't so damned good-looking, I'd probably report it to the authorities as abuse :-)

Comment: Dear user409345: this question, phrased as it is, is *not a real question* by my guidebook

Answer (score 1):

This is really not related to HAL or D-Bus at all. Telepathy's definitely not the answer: it's an IM framework. :) If I were you, I'd look at [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/), which is the standard multimedia framework on the Linux desktop, via the [pygst](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) binding.

You'll want to use the `gconfaudiosrc` element to pull audio from the default microphone, and send it to `gconfaudiosink`. To check that this works, run `gst-launch-0.10 gconfaudiosrc ! gconfaudiosink` in a terminal: you should hear everything you say into your microphone echoed out of your speakers.

This [blog post by the Internet's Jono Bacon](http://www.jonobacon.org/2006/08/28/getting-started-with-gstreamer-with-python/) might be a good starting point. You could try modifying it to use `gconfaudiosrc` rather than `filesrc`, `decodebin` and `audioconvert`. You could also take a look at [this tutorial](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/index.html); the [GStreamer Application Development Manual](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/index.html) is a lot more detailed.

Comment: This information is very useful for me.thank you very much for your responce.